# How to bind event for td which is rendered only on another button click?

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I need to add a hover listener for td which is get rendered only when the button is clicked.

```
<div class="ui-fileupload-content ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
    <table class="ui-fileupload-files">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="ui-fileupload-preview"></td>
                <td>Sample File.xlsx</td><td>42.4 KB</td>
                <td class="ui-fileupload-progress">
                    <div class="ui-progressbar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
                        <div class="ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header ui-corner-left" style="display: none; width: 0%;"></div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here I have to add hover only for Sample File.xlsx42.4 KB this td.

Comment: Your question is unclear, please see [ask]. There is no hover listener, but `onmouseover/-out/-enter/-leave`-events may help you.

Comment: This is a bad approach. If you're working with PrimeFaces, you should not thing in your page as a set of HTML elements. You should use Primefaces' elements instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have add the bind the hover event on the button click 

$(".importFileUpload .ui-fileupload-content .ui-fileupload-files tr td:nth-child(2)").hover((function(){
                    console.log("On hover");
                }),(function(){
                    console.log("on mouse out");
                }));
```